# perforce, shelve testing failing

Tags: perforce, shelve

My Shelve testing build is failing, and it is giving me:

```
Project file 'e:\p4\tech\...\someproject.vcproj' could not be loaded.
The project is either missing from disk or access was denied.
```

whereas the projet is actually present on my local system.

There is also a new project that I am adding to the perforce tree, for which:
The new path is already added in the client spec, so that it gets mapped to the new project. However, it still complaints that:

```
Project file 'e:\p4\tech\...\newproject.vcproj' could not be loaded.
The project is either missing from disk or access was denied.
```

Please let me know how should I go about fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me.  You're trying to build a Visual Studio project, I guess.  Are you working in the IDE, or using a CI tool?  The three dots in the path are also strange; those three dots are a Perforce wildcard but wouldn't make sense to a build tool.